# can't access instance variables syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I don't seem to understand why can't I get access to the instance variables if they are not initialize. I get the following error when I add the instance variable to attr_accessor.

```
syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
attr_reader :name :list
```

I am able to access the attribute methods of name and age but not the other ones. Here is my code.

```
class Dancer
  attr_reader :name
  attr_accessor :age :list 

  def initialize(name, age)
    @name = name
    @age = age
    @list = []
  end

  def pirouette
    "*twirls*"
  end

  def bow
    "*bows*"
  end

  def queue_dance_with(partner)
    @partner = partner
  end

  def card
    @list << @partner
  end

  def begin_next_dance
    puts "Now dancing with #{@list[0]}"
    @list.shift
  end
end
```

Why can't I access `@partner` and `@list`? if I add them to `attr_accessor` or `attr_reader :list :partner` it gives me an error.

Comment: This is a pure-Ruby question so it should not have a Rails tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comma matters:

```
#                 ⇓
attr_accessor :age, :list
```

Comment: I have a question does this class already comes with array methods included? or do I have to add the array module to have access to array methods? and if so how would I go about doing this?

Comment: I am getting the following error in the card method ```undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass```

Comment: This class comes with 6 methods, none of them might be qualified as “array method,” I guess. There is no `Array` module in ruby. I have no idea about any other parts of this code, I have just [correctly] answered the question that was stated.

Comment: Somehow the instance variable `@list` is set with `nil`. Since you are defining it with an `attr_accessor`, it could be modified outside this class.

Comment: @Fredius `attr_accessor` **does not define** local variables. It defines getter and setter methods for it.

Comment: I know, I'm just saying that since you use `attr_accessor`, you lose "control" of that instance variable. It can be modified somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

You missed the `,`

```
attr_accessor :age, :list
```

Comment: I am getting the following error in the card method ```undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass```